# How do different grammar theory (e.g. PSG, FG) explain word order in different language?

Tags: grammar, linguistic-typology, generative-grammar, dependency-grammar

In typology, how do different types of grammar theories (such as phrase structure grammar, functional grammar, etc.) explain different linear word order in different languages? I know that dependency distance is used to explain the word order in dependency grammar. Therefore, I do want to be exposed to other theories and know how those theories explain the different linear order.

Or put it in the other way, in typology, which grammar theory has been used as its theoretical foundation? Do you have some papers, articles, or books for recommendation?

I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Please try to do some of your own research on this before posting. Thanks.